Debezium Kafka Connect / Mongo Connector silently failing, only spawning 1 worker, not creating topics, no errors
I am currently trying to deploy a 2.4.0.FINAL Debezium connector onto a Mongo 4.4 version instance.
However, my connector does not seem to work. I have metadata topics (ie, connect-offsets and connect-status) created and can see via DEBUG logs that my connections to both kafka and Mongo seem to work. However, this is a 3 shard replica set and I can see only 1 worker and no collection topics are created, via the REST api. The previous version of this connector correctly works with 3 workers (albeit a different kafka cluster). I can also verify changes are actually occurring to the collections of note.
I am wracking my brain relentlessly. With debug logging enabled, I see logs like the following which should to me indicate at least something is happening... I've read over thousands of logs and nothing is currently out of place or strange at all. However, the connector statuses and worker counts do not match what is expected, nor are any topics created or changes emitted.
I'd appreciate any help as I'm quite lost at this point. One thing to note is the schema registry does contain collection schemas, but for every single collection in the db.
Using BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=...
Successfully authenticated with broker.... 
Finished authentication with no session expiration and no session re-authentication
Set SASL client state to COMPLETE

...

Received assignment: Assignment...
Currently running assignment: Assignment...
Finished starting connectors and tasks

...

Checking current members of replica set at host1, host2, host3
Received batch of 0 documents with cursorId ... from server ...
Sending command '{"hello": 1, "$db": "admin", ...}] to server ...
Execution of command with request id ... completed successfully in 34.15 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:...}] to server ...
checking for more records...
Received batch of 0 documents with cursorId ... from server host2...
no records available or batch size not reached yet, sleeping a bit...
Checking status of ...
Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[...]}

My config for my connector is as follows. Some configs may be superflous and just hopeful, but they generally match what I expect from this release documentation
{
    "name": "my-connector",
    "config": {
        "collection.include.list": "db.collection1, db.collection2...",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
        "database.include.list": "db",
        "snapshot.max.threads": "4",
        "mongodb.connection.string": "mongodb://host1:...,host2:...,host3:...",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "bootstrap:...",
        "mongodb.name": "name",
        "mongodb.password": "${file:/mongoauth/...}",
        "mongodb.user": "${file:/mongoauth/...}",
        "name": "my-connector",
        "snapshot.mode": "never",
        "source.struct.version": "v2",
        "tasks.max": "7",
        "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
        "capture.mode": "change_streams_update_full",
        "topic.prefix": "prefix",
        "topic.creation.enable": "true",
        "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",
        "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "-1",
        "topic.creation.default.partitions": "-1"
    },
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "source"
}


Querying the REST apis, I'm seeing odd responses:
GET localhost:8083/connectors

[
    "my-connector"
]

GET localhost:8083/connectors?expand=info&expand=status 
{
    "my-connector": {
        "info": {
            "name": "my-connector",
            "config": {
                ...
            },
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "connector": "my-connector",
                    "task": 0
                }
            ],
            "type": "source"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "my-connector",
            "connector": {
                "state": "RUNNING",
                "worker_id": "...:8083"
            },
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "state": "RUNNING",
                    "worker_id": "...:8083"
                }
            ],
            "type": "source"
        }
    }
}

GET localhost:8083/connectors/my-connector/topics/
{
    "my-connector": {
        "topics": []
    }
}

I really am expecting 3 tasks on this connector as I have 3 hosts and can see from the logs that all 3 are discovered.
